# how to detect grid view in edit mode at row data bound

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

i just want to detect that grid view in row editing mode and i just want to bind drop down list at this moment. i found many article and i make this code :

```
 protected void GV_ViewCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_Types1");
                dl.DataSource = db.PartyTypes.Select(t => t).ToList();
                dl.DataBind();
                dl.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "type_id").ToString();
                DropDownList dl1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_CountryNames1");
                dl1.DataSource = db.Countries.Select(c => c).ToList();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "country_id").ToString()))
                {
                    dl1.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "country_id").ToString();
                    DropDownList dl2 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_StateNames1");
                    dl2.DataSource = db.States.Where(s => s.country_id.Equals(int.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "country_id").ToString()))).Select(s => s).ToList();
                    dl2.DataBind();
                }
                DataRowView rowView1 = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                if (rowView1["UserOFC"] != null)
                {
                    (e.Row.FindControl("chk_UserOFC1") as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.DataItem.Equals("UserOFC").ToString());
                }
                if (rowView1["UserVAT"] != null)
                {
                    (e.Row.FindControl("chk_UserVAT1") as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.DataItem.Equals("UserVAT").ToString());
                }
                if (rowView1["UserINV"] != null)
                {
                    (e.Row.FindControl("chk_UserINV1") as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.DataItem.Equals("UserINV").ToString());
                }
                if (rowView1["UserNone"] != null)
                {
                    (e.Row.FindControl("chk_UserNone1") as CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.DataItem.Equals("UserNone").ToString());
                }
            }
            UpdatePanel10.Update();
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_Types");
                ddl1.DataSource = db.PartyTypes.Select(p => p).ToList();
                ddl1.DataBind();
                DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_CountryNames");
                ddl2.DataSource = db.Countries.Select(c => c).ToList();
                ddl2.DataBind();
            }
        }
}
```

how ever footer drop down list successfully binds up but in edit item template not.

please help me...

```
protected void GV_ViewCustomers_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
       GV_ViewCustomers.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
       this.FillGrid((String)Session["StartAlpha"] ?? null, (int)Session["GroupByENTYPE"] , (String)Session["ColumnName"] ?? null, (String)Session["SearchText"] ?? null);
       UpdatePanel10.Update();
       MPE.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what your issue actually is, but you need to check for  `RowState=Edit` also in the footer.

So instead of:

```
protected void GV_ViewCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        // ...
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

this:

```
protected void GV_ViewCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow
        && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer 
        && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: why should i have to check at footer side i just only work with DataControlRowState.Edit.

Comment: @Shal: i don't understand, you are using `DataControlRowState.Edit` only for normal rows but not for the footer-row which means that the code is always executed, even if you are not in edit mode.

Comment: ok i miss one line just look at my code i miss one line dl1.databind() so it's not bind up. any ways thank you

Comment: this will not work for rows that have Odd row Index. For e.g Try to edit the 2nd row in the gridview, the if logic will return false

Comment: & bitwise operator is very important here as this enum is flags based meaning it can be or'd with other enums. For example, when an even row is clicked, the RowType will be Alternate | Edit. Bitwise is absolutely necessary here (you need to know if the Edit bit was turned on).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit || e.Row.RowState ==
(DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate))
{
  // write your statement that you want to fire in Edit mode
}
```

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/123/how-to-check-for-edit-mode-of-the-gridview-row-irrespective-of-it-is-n